# How to redirect to new view after successful login in XCode using PHP and mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, ios

I have a project which is an Ipad application. I am using Xcode with PHP and mysql database.

I have a login view, which should verify the username and password of the user by checking the database through PHP and then it should move the user to his profile view.

in PHP, I know that the statement: ex.( header ("Location: profile.php") ) will move the user to the  page (profile.php).

my questions are:

which statement do I have to use to move from one view to another using php and xcode, 
instead of moving to a php page?
how to make a session for my login code?

here is my PHP code:

```
<?php

//Getting entered values
$username = $_GET['name'];
$password = $_GET['pass'];

//database info 
$DB_HostName = "localhost";
$DB_Name = "test";
$DB_User = "root";
$DB_Pass = "";
$DB_Table = "user";

//connecting to database
$con = mysql_connect($DB_HostName,$DB_User,$DB_Pass);
mysql_select_db("$DB_Name");


//Create query
$qry="SELECT * FROM user WHERE name='$username' AND pass='$password' ";
$result=mysql_query($qry);



while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)){

if($row['pass']== $password){
echo $row['name'];
}else{
echo'error';
}

?>
```

here is my objective c code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController


- (void)enterCredential{

    NSMutableString *mtURL = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://localhost     /login.php?name=%@&pass=%@",username.text ,password.text];


    [mtURL setString:[mtURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSData * dataUrl = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:mtURL]];
    NSMutableString * mtResult = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:dataUrl encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"PHP fatmah %@", mtResult);
}

@end
```

Comment: Have you tried using the value that is echoed back from your php?

Comment: @Wain No.. how can I view the data that i got from the PHP file in a textfield ?

Comment: You are already logging the text that is returned.

Comment: is it safe to pass the username and password like this NSMutableString *mtURL = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://localhost     /login.php?name=%@&pass=%@",username.text ,password.text]; ? Is there any other way like we submit the php form with POST?

Answer (score 0):

> which statement do I have to use to move from one view to another
>   using php and xcode, instead of moving to a php page?

In Objective C you do that by performing a segue from one controller to the other read up on the function [performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/performSegueWithIdentifier%3asender%3a)

> how to make a session for my login code?

You can set a flag from your php that will determine wether the login is valid or not.
If authenticated you can use [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to store the values you need.
That flag could be a boolean that you send from your php script to your iPad app.